# angularjs freezes page when loading / displaying new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently programming an angularjs app which fetches articles (around 50 but it also happens already with 20) and displays them. Each article has its own directive and the main template iterates over the articles array with ng-repeat and displayes the directive for each article. Data is fetched asynchronous with the $http module.

The problem is that the page freezes when the data is received. I think its a problem with displaying the changed articles? Currently I implemented it that way once data arrives from the server it is assigned to the array wich is looped in the template.

I looked into the chrome timeline and discovered after the "loading finished" event an "XHR Ready State Change" event which is really long. In this event are lots of "DomSubtreeModified" events.

So my guess is that its taking so long for angular to change the view. Is there a way to prevent this?

I need an updating list of articles because you can load another chunk of articles which replaces the old one. Maybe there is a better way of handling this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it with less data first. I that works better, you know the problem. Maybe you have to do partial loading of the articles (do you really need to load them all at once?)

Comment: @Baszz: Thanks for your answer. This already happens with only 20 or even 10 articles with a shorter freeze. As I understand ng-repeat loading data after each other will trigger every article directive to be triggered again once the array changes.